# Create requirejs module with grunt

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, amd

How to create requirejs module with Grunt?

I have an assembled javascript file in `build/assembly.js`.

In that file I have an plain javascript modules (without `define(){...}` wrapper).

I want to make requirejs amd module from that javascript assembly file with Grunt.

Answer (score 1):

Very late, but I was searching for something similar and found: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-require-wrapper

This grunt package will take a JS file and wrap it in a typical requireJs header.